# Sequent calculus - where should I start?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, sequent-calculus

I am given this formulae. $A \land B \implies C \lor D \lor E$

I want to deduce this formulae with sequent calculus. But my problem is that I dont know where to start, or which rule to take first. Because if I take $\land-R$ rule first, I am getting different leaves at the end and if I take $\land-L$ first, I am getting different leaves at the and.

What is the exact rule for where and with what to start?

Answer (score 2):

You can't deduce it, as it isn't a valid sequent ....

Comment: in my texbook it was deduced - and was said that this deduction was even a proof as leaves are axioms

Comment: Which book, where?

Comment: Maybe you should copy the whole question from your book. 

I know you would not ask rubbish question given your credit. But if there are no other assumptions, how the sentence above valid when A = B = true, and 
C = D = E = false.